# Can't update `mysql-workbench` on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql-workbench

I want to install the new version of `mysql-workbench` (6.2).
I can't update it with `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`.
I think it's because that I have `mysql-workbench` 6 ; That is the newest version of it in the repository.

So, now I want to know how can I install the newest version of a program with `apt-get install`.
How do we install a program from a repository? I mean, technically. Who updates the package in there? And when do they put the new version of a package there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get install` downloads and installs the version that is currently in the repository. To get updates you type `apt-get upgrade` which will install any updates that are released for Ubuntu and other installed applications.

Few applications are kept up to date in the repositories; the web browser Firefox is one of them. Ubuntu takes what is in Debian Testing or Sid and keeps it at those package versions that works on a Ubuntu release. This keeps the system in a stable state. Security updates are usually provided to Ubuntu packages, but not new versions.

To get the newest version of applications you will need to find [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)'s or [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). After adding either one you can then install the new application with `apt-get install <new package>`